# Is there a way to wait for an Element to appear in DOM and get the inner text simultaneously in Protractor

Tags: angular, promise, protractor

I have an alert which appears in the DOM after 0.5 seconds of a successful event, stays on the page for 3 seconds and then disappears. I want to wait for the element to appear on the DOM and validate the success message. The way I tried doing this is:

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false).then(() => {       // disable angular wait because once the alert appears a timer starts for it to disappear.
   browser.wait(this.EC.presenceOf(elem), 15000, "Alert took too long to appear on page").then(() => {
       expect(elem.getText()).toBe(alertMessage);
   })
}).then(() => {
   browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);     // enable the angular wait
});
```

Well, when I actually check the text available in the element, I get an error like this on the console:

```
- Expected '' to be 'My Alert Message'.
```

I don't actually know, why will this happen. Is it taking too long for the wait promise to resolve? Does the element disappear when I reach the next block or only the text disappears?

After being unable to figure this out I wonder if I can validate the text simultaneously when I check for the element's presence? Or if you can give suggestions on how else to achieve my goal here.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out the problem here. The text inside the element was not updated as soon as the element appeared on the DOM, to fix this:

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false).then(() => {       // disable angular wait because once the alert appears a timer starts for it to disappear.
       browser.wait(this.EC.presenceOf(elem), 15000, "Alert took too long to appear on page").then(() => {
           browser.wait(() => {
               return elem.getText().then((innerText) => {
                   return innerText != '';
               })
           }, 3000, "Alert disappeared before reading the text inside it").then(() => {
               expect(elem.getText()).toBe(alertMessage);
           })
       })
    }).then(() => {
       browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);     // enable the angular wait
    });
```

But I am not sure if the speed of the execution can be trusted so that the text is read before the alert disappears.